# What does view function time mean in New Relic

Tags: python, django, newrelic

I have an api built in django. I am using new relic to analyze the response times. New relic is reporting in one of my views the the view function itself "api_v1.views:get_places" is taking up 70% of the time while the database transactions are only taking up a fraction of the time.

What exactly does the view function time mean in new relic? Is this the time it takes for django to route the request or is this the amount of time it spends in the function excluding all the db queries?

heres what new relic looks like
[image: newrelic]

Comment: I don't know much about new relic, but does get_places have geographic information? Perhaps the response is large enough and Django is spending some time while serializing all that geo information in JSON. That can take quite some time (from my experience)

Comment: yeh but its only 75 rows does that sounds like a lot? the db queries are all super fast

Comment: What is the expected size of get_places? Doesn't seem like a lot of data, but without seeing actual code for get_places it's impossible to help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the code. I really just want to know views:get_places is in new relic.

Comment: I haven't used newrelic with django before, so there may be some difficulty in the return of information from django to newrelic. But in other areas I've used newrelic, it definitely is returning the time it spent in that particular segment. So this is telling you that 68.4% of the time is spent processing within that function. It is not rolling in the amount of time spent in database transactions, other web transactions, etc.

Comment: ok awesome thats what I was looking for... actually found the issue already post this as an answer and i'll accept